# By-passing the shuffling stage of Mapreduce job in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, asynchronous, mapreduce

I am trying to implement an algorithm where only single reducer is required and mapreduce job is executing iteratively. Result of each mapper in particular iteration is to be added in reducer and then processed. Then output of the reducer is passed as input to mapper in other iteration. I want to execute the job in asynchronous manner i.e. as soon as pre-defined number of mappers are executed, pass the output directly to the reducer i.e. avoiding the shuffling and sorting as its creating only overhead for my algorithm. Is that even possible? If not, what can be done for asynchronous exceution of mapreduce job at implementation level. I went to number of research papers but unable to get any idea from there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to code up you own custom solution for this. I did a similar thing in a project recently.

It requires a bit of code, so I can only outline the steps here :)

- set `mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps` to `0.0` so that the reducer comes up before the mappers finish (this will give you a speedup right away btw. try it out before going ahead with below steps ;) maybe it's enough)
- Implement your own `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapOutputCollector` that writes the shuffle output to Socket instead of to the standard shuffle path (this is the mapper side)
- Implement your own `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleConsumerPlugin` that waits for connections by mappers and reads pairs from the network (this is the reducer side)

Things you will need to do:

- Synchronize the mappers not starting before that reducer is actually listening (Zookeeper is what I used here)
- Adjust your job configs to use the custom mapper and reducer components

Futher reading: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/PluggableShuffleAndPluggableSort.html

Def. doable, but requires some effort :)

Comment: Thanks!! I tried setting slowstart to 0.0 but it didn't reflect well. I'll definitely try other steps. :)

Comment: as you mentioned in second step about writing MapOutput to Socket instead of MapOutputFile.  Which socket are you refering here?

Comment: @Mohini some Socket that is listening on the Reducer side

Comment: for reading and writing to socket I need to know the machine on which reduce task is scheduled.. how to figure that out? That is how to get the address of that system?

Comment: @Mohini easiest way I know is doing what I suggested and using Zookeeper for that. You can make the reduce task simply write its own IP together with the partition it handles to some ZK path and then read it from there on the Mapper :)

Comment: as per you suggested I used zookeeper for the same and now ReduceTask is writing its own address to the zookeeper path. But as per the Hadoop's property all the map containers are launched before the reducer one, so when maptask client will be looking for connecting to the Reduce Task server and server won't be running.. it will throw Connection refused error.

Comment: @Mohini that's what `mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps` is for, it makes the reduce tasks fire up before the mappers. That said you still have to somehow block in the mappers to wait for the reducers to fully come up (need some Zookeeper latch for that).